# Dual of Model Weil group $E(K)$ over a local field $K$ is $H^1(G_K,E)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, duality-theorems

Let $K$ be a local field.
Let $G_K=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ be an absolute Galois group of $K$.

Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.

Let $E(K)^*=Hom_{\Bbb{Z}}(E(K),\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$ be a Pontryagin dual of $E(K)$.

I want to prove the following isomorphism.
How can I prove this isomorphism ?

> $E(K)^* \cong H^1(G_K,E)$

Since $E(K)=H^0(G_K, E)$, if we admit this isomorphism, Pontryagin dual changes $H^0$ to $H^1$ in local case, so this may be a certain local duality theorem of cohomology which I cannot explicitly write down.

Comment: There is an 'direct' proof for the Tate curve $E_q/K$:  see exercise 5.14 of Silverman's Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. Do you have a copy/ do you follow the argument  sketched there? (buyer beware: in my edition, there seems to be a typo in the statement of local CFT.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fun of it is the Barsotti-Weil theorem, which says that for any abelian variety $A$ over $K$ we have $\widehat{A}(K) = \text{Ext}^1(A, \mathbb{G}_m)$, where $\widehat{A}$ is the dual abelian variety (elliptic curves are self-dual, of course). It's easy to say what the map between these groups is: a point of $\widehat{A}(K)$ is a degree $0$ line bundle on $A$, and removing the zero-section from such a bundle gives an extension of the group $A$ by $\mathbb{G}_m$. However, I don't know the proof that this map is an isomorphism.

Even spotting this, the work isn't done, since you need to identify extensions with Galois cohomology. Milne does this in Chapter I.3 of *Arithmetic Duality Theorems*, although he doesn't prove the Barsotti-Weil theorem itself.

Comment: "easy" -- hmm, no, why is line-bundle-minus-zero-section a group?? must use the degree zero-ness somewhere.

Comment: If $L$ has degree zero, we have a natural homomorphism $\tau_{x+y}^{\ast}L \cong \tau_x^{\ast} L \otimes \tau_y^{\ast} L$, so we get well-behaved maps $L_x \otimes L_y \rightarrow L_{x+y}$. But turning this into a group law looks painful.

Comment: @hunter Fwiw, see my comment to the original post.